# correct me on a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

There are two sentences below. Can anyone tell me which one is correct or are both wrong? If so, what is the correct way to say them?

- > Happiness is witnessing a rain in summer.
- > Happiness is being witness a rain in summer.

By the above sentences I wanted to express "I am happy to see a rainy day in the summer".

One more thing, can I use "a rain" to represent a short period of rain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with your last question first, because we need to modify your original sentences so they make sense first.

> One more thing, can I use "a rain" to represent a short period of
>   rain?

No, you can not use the indefinite article to refer to rain, as rain as you have described it, is not a singular noun but is synonymous with *rain drops*, note plural, or *rain fall* which also does not take the indefinite article.

The singular noun rain has a different meaning:

***Rain***

> 1.2 (singular) A large or overwhelming quantity of things that fall or descend.
>
> ‘he fell under the rain of blows’
>   ([OLD](http://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rain))

## 1

Your first sentence:

> Happiness is witnessing a rain in summer

Rewritten to make sense:

> Happiness is witnessing rain in summer.

Or

> Happiness is witnessing rainfall in summer.

## 2

Your second sentence:

> Happiness is being witness a rain in summer.

Rewritten to make sense:

> Happiness is being witness to rain in summer.

*Being witness* and *witnessing* are synonymous so both the modified sentences 1 and 2 mean the same thing.

Both however do not specify the period of time over which you witnessed rainfall to make you happy. It could have been a 1 minute shower, days, or even weeks.

So in fact given that:-

> By the above sentences [you] wanted to express "I am happy to see a rainy day in the summer".

You would be better saying exactly that, which makes sense unmodified:

> "I am happy to see a rainy day in the summer".

Or more idiomatically:

> It makes me happy to see a rainy day in summer.

Note that the indefinite article works fine here because it is referring to the singular *day* which is described as *rainy* and not the singular noun *rain*.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, 1 should be correct, possibly with minor modifications. Here, "witnessing a rain in summer" is acting as a noun. The way it is written, it can be ambiguous, with "is witnessing" being a verb.

Depending on where you are using the sentence, maybe you could write "Happiness is, witnessing a rain in summer." But I'm not fully confident about that either because of the comma.